# Find and highlight duplicate decimal values in excel

Tags: excel, duplicates

i'm looking for a way to highlight duplicate values in a column in excel. These are numeric values defined as Text. Problem is when I use the normal duplicate conditional format it doesn't work completely.[duplicate conditional format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcYTf.gif)
The values have single or double decimals for instance: 3.1 and 3.10. when I use the conditional format it highlights both 3.1 and 3.10. My question is how am i able to differentiate between the two values so they won't be highlighted. I've tried using a VBA code which loops through every cell in the column to check for duplicates but I have a list containing 100,000 values so this is extremely slow (10 min to complete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a title row on the column (I could only get this to work omitting the first cell in the column):

You can use this formula for conditional formatiing, applied to K2 onwards to the end of the sheet (I used column K when I built it but adjust column label accordingly).

This works a charm as MATCH will only find exact matches and return an error if they are not found, the conditional formatting formula checks above and below for a duplicate value and highlights both in the same way the automatic feature works.

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(K2,$K3:$K$1048571,0)),IF(ISERROR(MATCH(K2,$K$1:$K1,0)),FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)`

Only problem is that this **only works if all cells are formatted as text** and not just those with leading .0's. (2.51 right aligned is entered as number formatting)

[image: Example]

Comment: Much better performance than `SUMPRODUCT`. I had thought about `MATCH` too but was not able to get how to look upwards and downwards using the same formula. +1.

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Perfect! Glad to hear it. Thanks @AxelRichter, I was trying all sorts of messy long formulas before I realised that MATCH was behaving correctly.